# Identifying concept drift in the presence of data drift

Tags: hypothesis-testing, change-point, concept-drift, data-drift

Usually concept drift is defined as a change in the conditional distribution of our target variable with our covariates,
$P_{0}(Y|X) \neq P_{t}(Y|X)$. It is also known as *real concept drift* or *conditional drift* (according to https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2523813).

*Data drift* is defined as a change in the covariates $ P_0(X) \neq P_t(X)$. Now, assuming that no data drift has occurred, one can test for concept drift (for example by examining the residuals of a model, comparing them at the different time points). But how can one test for concept drift in the presence of data drift? Are there any known references?